# How to round number's fractional part to significant figures?

Tags: python

I'd like to automatically round numbers to *x* significant figures, but only their fractional part.

Desired output:

```
123 >>> 123.00
123.123 >>> 123.12
1.12 >>> 1.12
0.1 >>> 0.10
0.1234 >>> 0.12
0.01234 >>> 0.012
0.0001254 >>> 0.00013
```

I'm trying to achieve the most simple solution.

Comment: You can use `round(number, 2)` to get 2 digits after the decimal point. But I don't think there's anything built-in that will ignore the leading zeroes after the decimal point.

Comment: Do you just want to print the output?

Comment: @Jacob ye, the string is enough, and I don't think there's a possibility to keep the trailing *zeros* in a float type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out such a solution:

```py
def round_to_frac_sigfig(num, sigfigs):
    sigfig_pos = int(floor(log10(abs(num))))
    if sigfig_pos >= 0:
        formatter = "{:.%df}" % sigfigs
        return formatter.format(num)
    else:
        ndigits = -sigfig_pos + sigfigs - 1
        formatter = "{:.%df}" % ndigits
        return formatter.format(num)
```

If you don't care about the trailing *zeros*, here's a shorter solution:

```py
def round_to_frac_sigfig(num, sigfigs):
    sigfig_pos = int(floor(log10(abs(num))))
    if sigfig_pos >= 0:
        return round(num, sigfigs)
    else:
        return round(num, -sigfig_pos + sigfigs - 1)
```